# Call cancelled - Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, logout

In our application login page is not a part of the app itself. So to navigate to it, we use hardcore redirect to `/login` after we did a logout call to backend.

The weird thing is, the Logout API call is sometimes cancelled. And then the app is still up and running, user is logged in and it redirects to home page (because the route /logout doesn't exist).

This doesn't happen locally and also not on Mac, I've only seen it on a Windows machine with Chrome and Firefox.

What's wrong here?

PS I have no idea which code will be helpful, so please let me know if you need something.

```js
// call
public logout(): void {
        this.applicationSandbox.logout()
            .subscribe(x => {
                window.location.href = '/login';
            });
    }

// sandbox 
public logout(): Observable<void> {
        return this.authenticationService.logout()
            .map(empty =>            this.store.dispatch(clearAuthentication()));
    }

// service
public logout(): Observable<void> {
        return this.http.get(`/app/rest/logout`)
            .map(response => null);
    }
```

```html
<a href='/login' (click)="logout()" 
   [routerLinkActive]="'vb-navbar__item--active'"></a>
```

Comment: Can you create a small plunkr to show this? You can use Fiddler or something similar to see what is going on once you initiate `logout`

Comment: I've added some additional code.

Comment: So you know which one of these two logouts doesn't reach map? Just to make this clear - route `/app/rest/logout` doesn't exist and responds with home page?

Comment: ehm, this is not the route, it's API call to backend. I've edited my explanation, so it's more clear now